# bind an empty file in the host to a non empty file in the container does not write file content to host

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a docker compose as such that starts a MySQL db:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  mysql_db:
    container_name: mysql_db
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - /root/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass

volumes:
  mysql_data:
    name: mysql_data
```

Note that `/root/mysql/my.cnf` is an empty file in the host and `/etc/my.cnf` is a non empty file with default configurations for MYSQL server. I was expecting that files on the host behave the same as empty directories on the host, if they are empty they get populated by the files present in the directory on the container.

The goal is here to add some configuration to allow `mysql` to receive incoming connections from all addresses.

If my file `root/mysql/my.cnf` has this line:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
```

it will basically overwrite all default configuration into `etc/my.conf`

Comment: can you clarify? on one hand you say you want the file inside the container to appear on host, on the other you say you want to use the host file to change the behaviour in the container. docker volumes do not merge files, if that is what you mean. You should copy /etc/my.cnf outside the container, customize it and then map it as a volume for the container to use

Comment: yes, I will try to copy and customise and see if it works then. I was expecting docker would copy the file content from the container into the file

Comment: that still did not work.

Comment: Docker bind mounts work the same way as normal Unix filesystem mounts, and the host content always replaces the image content; nothing is automatically copied anywhere.  The linked question describes a workaround which takes advantage of copying very specific to Docker named volumes.